# Bootstrap Modal + Carousel Gallery not showing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Bootstrap Modal + Carousel Gallery integrated than in my html file but somehow the when i click on my thumbnail, the modal images does not come up.

Here is my code.

```html
<!--Bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Latest stable release of jQuery Core Library-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-lZFHibXzMHo3GGeehn1hudTAP3Sc0uKXBXAzHX1sjtk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

<!--Bootstrap JS-->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>



<ul class="list-inline">
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="0"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://placeimg.com/200/133/nature/1"><br>
Caption</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="1"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://placeimg.com/200/133/nature/2"><br>
Caption</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="2"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://placeimg.com/200/133/nature/3"><br>
Caption</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="3"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://placeimg.com/200/133/nature/4"><br>
Caption</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="4"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://placeimg.com/200/133/nature/5"><br>
Caption</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#myGallery" data-slide-to="5"><img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://placeimg.com/200/133/nature/6"><br>
Caption</a></li>
<!--end of thumbnails-->
</ul>

<!--begin modal window-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<div class="pull-left">My Gallery Title</div>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" title="Close"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

<!--CAROUSEL CODE GOES HERE-->
<!--begin carousel-->
<div id="myGallery" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/1" alt="item0">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Slide 0  description.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/2" alt="item1">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Slide 1 description.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/3" alt="item2">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Slide 2  description.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/4" alt="item3">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Slide 3 description.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/5" alt="item4">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Slide 4 description.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item"> <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature/6" alt="item5">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Heading 3</h3>
<p>Slide 5 description.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!--end carousel-inner--></div>
<!--Begin Previous and Next buttons-->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myGallery" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myGallery" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
<!--end carousel--></div>


<!--end modal-body--></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<div class="pull-left">
<small>Photographs by <a href="https://placeimg.com" target="new">placeimg.com</a></small>
</div>
<button class="btn-sm close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<!--end modal-footer--></div>
<!--end modal-content--></div>
<!--end modal-dialoge--></div>
<!--end myModal-->></div>
```

And here is the reference where i copied the steps.  [HERE](https://alt-web.com/TUTORIALS/?id=bootstrap_modal_carousel_gallery)

I can share my page file but question is, why do did i run into such issues?
I'd appreciate all and any help i can get here from anybody!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not come up" ? do you mean it doesn't open? I've tested your code in a local server and it works fine.

Comment: Here is what i mean. I have the same code here http://deckard.rf.gd/projects.html  you can see what's happening here.

Comment: Looks like a conflict between Scripts, Try to keep only jquery and Bootstrap and disable all scripts one by one start with Google Maps.

Comment: Alright. I will try that.

Comment: Yay! You are right. I disabled some of the slider scripts i have on it. And it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Another thing i am having issue with is the CSS. The contents over flow is not set. I tried adding this overflow: auto; in the CSS but it's not working

Comment: I added an answer to add some codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main issue was a conflict between slider scripts.

About CSS overflow:

Just enable the `height: 450px` in `.project-content` class and add `overflow-y: auto;` to it.